# Can't get access token for ExactOnline with OAuth

Tags: ruby, oauth, oauth-2.0, httparty, exact-online

I'm following the OAuth tutorial [here](https://developers.exactonline.com/Content/OAuth_Tutorial.html) to get a access code in order to authenticate my API requests to the online accounting software Exact Online.

However, I'm stuck at step 3, where I use the authorization code returned in step 2 to obtain the access token.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
require 'httparty'

EXACT_CLIENT_ID = '<REDACTED>'
EXACT_CLIENT_SECRET = '<REDACTED>'
EXACT_SERVER_BASE_URL = 'https://start.exactonline.nl'
EXACT_AUTH_CODE = '<REDACTED>'

response = HTTParty.post("#{EXACT_SERVER_BASE_URL}/api/oauth2/token", headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, query: {code: EXACT_AUTH_CODE, redirect_uri: 'http://<REDACTED>.runscope.net/', grant_type: 'authorization_code', client_id: EXACT_CLIENT_ID, client_secret: EXACT_CLIENT_SECRET})

puts response
# => 'Bad request'

puts response.code
# => 400
```

I don't understand why this is happening. When looking at the list of response codes [here](https://developers.exactonline.com/Content/Resp%20codes%20Error%20handling.html), the code means:

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update #1:**

I've also tried:

```
response_2 = HTTParty.post("#{EXACT_SERVER_BASE_URL}/api/oauth2/token", :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, :body => {'code' => EXACT_AUTH_CODE, 'redirect_uri' => 'http://<REDACED>.runscope.net/', 'grant_type' => 'authorization_code', 'client_id' => EXACT_CLIENT_ID, 'client_secret' => EXACT_CLIENT_SECRET})
```

But the response is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though using the HTTP POST method you're providing the values as query parameters by supplying them to the `query:` parameter to the `.post` method. Instead you should provide them in the `body:` parameter, see: [How can I implement this POST request using HTTParty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461333/how-can-i-implement-this-post-request-using-httparty)

Also your syntax re. `body:` `:body` should be fixed, so it would look like:

```
response_2 = HTTParty.post("#{EXACT_SERVER_BASE_URL}/api/oauth2/token", :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, :body => {'code' => EXACT_AUTH_CODE, 'redirect_uri' => 'http://<REDACED>.runscope.net/', 'grant_type' => 'authorization_code', 'client_id' => EXACT_CLIENT_ID, 'client_secret' => EXACT_CLIENT_SECRET})
```

Last but not least: the code value is one-time usage only and has a short lifetime; make sure you use a freshly obtained one.

Comment: I've also tried using the `body:` parameter, see updated question above, but the result is the same...

Comment: the `code` value is one-time usage only and has a short lifetime; make sure you use a freshly obtained one

Comment: All working now! Please update your answer so I can accept