# Ruby/Sinatra - How can I call post in lambda class?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm make a little program in sinatra and I'm wanted to perfom some dynamic call of post, with diynamic uri, so I make a Connexion class like this:

```
class Connexion
  def initialize(path)
    @path = path
  end

  def sinatraPost
    post "/#{@path}" do
     # some code
  end
  end
end
```

But when I'm launch sinatraPost, I've got this error:

```
 undefined method `post' for #<Connexion:0x000000026206b8> (NoMethodError)
```

How can I call the sinatra post method in my class ?

EDIT: Okay ! So, I change my strategy, I have this following code:

```
class Webhook < Sinatra::Base

 get '/:name' do
  # compare with names array
 end
end

Webhook.run!
```

Thank's to everyone !

Comment: Sinatra’s `post` is a DSL, it is not intended to be called.

Comment: Do you want to make a `POST` call or receive it from others? It looks like you want the first ...

Comment: Ho.. I didn't know that, how can I do to perfom the same thing with a DSL ?

Comment: It's for waiting a github webhook notification at every push

Comment: If you want to send (as opposed to receive) a post in ruby perhaps [HTTParty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461333/how-can-i-implement-this-post-request-using-httparty) would suit you better.

Comment: I want to receive a post request from a github webhook, that's why I use sinatra

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're going about this the wrong way. If you want to set up your app to *receive* a POST request, you'll need routing logic in your controller. Sinatra controllers normally look like this:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/route1' do
  # do stuff
end

post '/route2' do
  # do stuff
end
```

If you're using a modular app, you'll want to have your app inherit from `Sinatra::Base`. See the [Sinatra docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps) for more.

*Making* a post request is different, and doesn't rely on Sinatra methods.

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI("http://google.com")
headers = {}
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, headers)
response = http.request(request)
```

Or something like that. Good luck!