# How to rewrite Post request in javascript in Ruby with Httparty

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

so I have code in JavaScript I am trying to rewrite in Ruby and I can't figure out how to pass these parameters and parse the response in the same way with Ruby that I do in JavaScript

The javascript code:

```
$.post(urlToPostTo, {
    name: nameToPost,
    captchatext: "",
    index: "0"
}).done(function (response) {
    var responseHTML = $.parseHTML(response);
    var tables = $(responseHTML).find("td");
    self.pA = $(tables[2]).text();
    self.dA = $(tables[3]).text();
    self.mR = $(tables[4]).text();
    deferred.resolve(data);
}).fail(function (error) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
});
```

Is there a way I can do this in Ruby (potentially with HTTParty)?

Comment: If you use `HTTParty` you can do something like `HTTParty.post(urlToPostTo)...`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461333/how-can-i-implement-this-post-request-using-httparty?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @jdgray yes, I know, Im having trouble getting the parameters passed correctly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you use HTTParty to post the body values and get a response using:

```
post_body = [{ "name" => nameToPost,
                     "captchatext" => "",
                     "index" => "0" }]
headers = {}
result = HTTParty.post(urlToPostTo, { :body => post_body, :headers => headers })
```

Next, you can use Nokogiri to parse the html and find the content in a way vary similar to jquery selectors:

```
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(result.response.body)
tables = html_doc.css("td")
tables[2]
...
```

Nokogiri guide: http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/

Comment: Getting an error that headers has to be a hash, and I'm still not getting the response expected even when fixed though

Comment: Sorry, it should be `headers = {}`

Comment: Sure - this is what I was doing but it seems that I am not getting the correct response though it is working in JS.. odd.

Comment: You can pass an extra parameter to help you debug the request. 

`HTTParty.post({ :body => post_body, :debug_output => $stdout}`

Comment: Can't really tell what is wrong based on this output - seems it must be a server/response issue though, going to mark this correct despite not having figured it out as this answers the original question

Comment: can you simulate the original request with javascript? use the chrome network tab to check all the headers passed. Maybe something like a session cookie is sent as well.