# Can't POST results of ActiveRecord query via HTTParty

Tags: json, ruby, activerecord, sinatra, httparty

I'm running a simple Sinatra app where I need to query some data and send a POST via JSON to a webhook URL for processing. I'm not sure how to properly format the records I've retrieved for HTTParty.

The contacts are printing to /account/{account_id}/contacts.json how I want them, they data just isn't being sent successfully.

**app.rb**

```
get "/account/:account_id/contacts.json" do
  @contacts = Contact.where("sfid = ?", params[:account_id])
  HTTParty.post("https://hooks.webapp.com/hooks/catch/387409/1us4j3/",
  { 
    :body => [ @contacts ].to_json,
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
  })
  @contacts.to_json
end
```

Comment: First of all, there is a difference in how data is being printed `@contacts.to_json` and how they are send `[ @contacts ].to_json`. It can be the problem. But if it's not, we need more information about how are you sure it's not being sent.

Comment: 'where' already returns an array to variable  `@contacts` . So type of     `@contacts`  is already an array. I don't think there is need to convert to array again before converting to json.  `:body => @contacts.to_json`   is okay.

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata I'm sure it's not being send because I have a test route that sends
HTTParty.post("https://hooks.webapp.com/hooks/catch/387409/1us4j3/",
  { 
    :body => [ {:name => 'value1', :privacy => 'value2'} ].to_json,
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
  })
successfully and is caught by the webhook. The code I posted in my question does not get caught.

Comment: @Mayank I attempted at/contacts.to_json as you suggested and was presented with an internal server error and these logs - https://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/sh/60c2d37d-df78-43d9-ac1d-0dacc4f926eb/a74b9a1cb7b17950dcbdaf7f92dec470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error is

> 2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:183:in `send_request_with_body'

It does not found any body in your request. You are sending the parameters body and head inside a hash.

Try this:

```
get "/account/:account_id/contacts.json" do
  @contacts = Contact.where("sfid = ?", params[:account_id])
  HTTParty.post("https://hooks.webapp.com/hooks/catch/387409/1us4j3/",
    :body =>  @contacts.to_json,
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
  )
  @contacts.to_json
end
```

You can checkout this post also for any more information regarding HTTP post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455744/post-json-to-api-using-rails-and-httparty)

Hope this helps..