# POSTing JSON body causes Rack::QueryParser::InvalidParameterError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm simply trying to POST a JSON content-type http request from one Rails server to another.  Putting a `%` character in a value string in the JSON is causing the `Rack::QueryParser::InvalidParameterError` on the receiving server.

On Server A, I use the httparty gem to perform a POST request w/ a JSON body

```
obj = {"key":"<%= @results %>"}
resp = HTTParty.post('https://test-url.com/data',
:body => obj.to_json,
:options => { :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json' } })
```

On Server B, I just parse the JSON from the request body

```
req_body = request.body.read()
req_body_json = JSON.parse req_body
# do work with json
```

This process works fine unless the `obj = {"key":"<%= @results %>"}` contains `%` chars, in which case this occurs on server B:

```
Started POST "/data" for 10.244.1.3 at 2018-01-02 19:27:04 +0000
F, [2018-01-02T19:27:04.245275 #1] FATAL -- :
F, [2018-01-02T19:27:04.245331 #1] FATAL -- : Rack::QueryParser::InvalidParameterError (invalid %-encoding ({"key":"\u003c%)):
F, [2018-01-02T19:27:04.245358 #1] FATAL -- :
F, [2018-01-02T19:27:04.245397 #1] FATAL -- : rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/query_parser.rb:72:in `rescue in parse_nested_query'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/query_parser.rb:60:in `parse_nested_query'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/request.rb:468:in `parse_query'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/request.rb:343:in `POST'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:362:in `block (2 levels) in POST'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:107:in `block in parse_formatted_parameters'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:107:in `fetch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:107:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:361:in `block in POST'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/request.rb:57:in `fetch'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/request.rb:57:in `fetch_header'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:360:in `POST'
...
```

When I change `obj = {"key":"<%= @results %>"}` to `obj = {"key":"<= @results>"}` the exception does not occur.

As far I know `%` is a valid in JSON, what am I missing here?

Comment: `"<%= @results %>"` is an `erb` construct. Are you intending string interpolation? I assume (perhaps incorrectly) that this is not happening in a view. In which case it would be more like `"#{ @results }"`

Comment: Oops I should have been more clear about that.  Yes, I'm in fact trying to send code that would normally exist in a view .html.erb file, but I'm just sending it as a string. `"<%= @results %>"`, is just an example of a string that contains `%`s.  If the obj were `obj = {"key":"%something%"}` the problem still occurs.

Comment: Perhaps try `to_query` instead of `to_json`?

Comment: I'll gladly give it a try, though every example I've seen appears to use `to_json` for this task - such as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7617185/6837388

Comment: Apologies, I abstracted my HTTParty a long time ago. Just checked my code and in fact I use `to_json` as well. A misfire on my part.

Comment: @jvillian, Thank you anyway, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Considering they way how it's implemented here: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/38125db0d079d52a3b0da815150fa2135bb0110d/lib/httparty.rb#L559,

Your `body` and `headers` hash keys should be siblings, try the next:

```
resp = HTTParty.post('https://test-url.com/data',
  :body => obj.to_json,
  :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Accept' => 'application/json' }
)
```