# Error Creating Shipment for an Order in Ebay

Tags: ruby, ebay-api

This error has plagued me for about a week now... I'm trying to create a shipment in Ebay but I'm getting a 500 error code in the response. Here is a link to the documentation https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/fulfillment/resources/order/shipping_fulfillment/methods/createShippingFulfillment

I'm running this code in the production environment:

```
  @header = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': "Bearer #{@token}"
  }

  uri = URI.parse("https://api.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order/#{order.order_number}/shipping_fulfillment")

  # Create the HTTP objects
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  items = []
  order.items.each do |i|
    items << {"lineItemId": i[:id]}
  end
  params = {
    "lineItems": items,
    "shippedDate": Time.parse(date).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z"),
    "shippingCarrierCode": "USPS",
    "trackingNumber": tracking_number
  }

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, @header)


  request.body = params.to_json
  response = http.request(request)
  puts response.code #prints 500
```

My Error:

```
{"errors": [{
"errorId": 2003,
"domain": "ACCESS",
"category": "APPLICATION",
"message": "Internal error",
"longMessage": "There was a problem with an eBay internal system or process. Contact eBay developer support for assistance",
"parameters": [{
    "name": "reason",
    "value": "Failed to transform underlying error response, see logs."
}]
}]}
```

I paid for the premium developer support and I've yet to receive a response. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried submitting the same request with an empty body but that doesn't change the response. I have also tried changing the headers. If I add `'Accept': 'application/json'`, then I get a 500 error with an empty body. It doesn't make any sense.

**UPDATE**

From the suggestions in the comments, I have tried changing the params hash to:

```
params = {
    "lineItems": "[{\"lineItemId\":10025031700524,\"quantity\":1}]",
    "shippedDate": "2020-05-01T08:05:00.000Z",
    "shippingCarrierCode": "USPS",
    "trackingNumber": "9400111899562795104724"
  }
```

I have also tried running subsequent requests. I have also tried submitting the following JSON in the body:

```
request.body = {
    "lineItems": [
      {
        "lineItemId": "10025031700524",
        "quantity": "1"
      }
    ],
    "shippedDate": "2020-05-01T08:05:00.000Z",
    "shippingCarrierCode": "USPS",
    "trackingNumber": "9400111899562795104724"
  }.to_json
```

Each of these attempts produces the exact same error as before. I've tried changing the quantity to an integer & string as well.

**UPDATE 2**

Here are the contents of my request:

```
POST /sell/fulfillment/v1/order/24-04954-08727/shipping_fulfillment
content-type: application/json
authorization: Bearer v#i^1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
accept-encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
accept: */*
user-agent: Ruby
connection: close
host: api.ebay.com
content-length: 159
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
{"lineItems":[{"lineItemId":"10025031700524"}],"shippedDate":"2020-05- 01T08:05:00.000Z","shippingCarrierCode":"USPS","trackingNumber":"9400111899562795104724"}
```

Comment: @Canon they have this strange note in their documentation for this end point: `Note: In some cases, this call may succeed if you issue it once more after receiving this error.`

did you pay attention to it ? try their advice as a debugging step

Comment: try adding `"quantity" : 1` to your line item object and see what will be the response, since as I can see they did not make it clear if it is optional or not.

Comment: I took this from their docs:
`[{  "lineItemId": 6254458011, "quantity": 1 }]`
and then converted it `to_json`, then got:
`"[{\"lineItemId\":6254458011,\"quantity\":1}]"`
which sends `lineItemId` as an integer not string.

Comment: try doing: `items << {"lineItemId": i[:id].to_s}` and see if will work

Comment: if you have a test version end point of it try making a request with hard coding their example in the docs:
`{ "lineItems": [ { "lineItemId": "6254458011", "quantity": 1 } ],  "shippedDate": "2016-07-20T00:00:00.000Z", "shippingCarrierCode": "USPS", "trackingNumber": "1Z50992656936"}` as it is. and see what will you get.

Comment: @AbdullahFadhel I have updated the question. Thanks

Comment: `request.body = {
    "lineItems": [
      {
        "lineItemId": 10025031700524,# try this by removing the quotes
        "quantity": "1"
      }
    ],
    "shippedDate": "2020-05-01T08:05:00.000Z",
    "shippingCarrierCode": "USPS",
    "trackingNumber": "9400111899562795104724"
  }.to_json`

Comment: try submitting the body above without double quotes on `lineItemId`

Comment: @AbdullahFadhel I tried it but still getting the same error.

Comment: Could you share the output of the following: `puts("#{request.method} #{request.path}");request.to_hash.each{|header,values|puts("#{header}: #{values.join(', ')}")};puts;puts(request.body)`? Of course **mocking your token**. This might give us a better view on what you're actually sending to the Ebay server.

Comment: Using Net::HTTP directly is always a huge pain in the ass because it's easy to shoot yourself in the foot. I recommend retrying with a higher level library like https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty. Here's an example of making this type of request with HTTParty: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7455744/3784008

Comment: Do you have the correct OAuth scope(s)  for your application?

Comment: @3limin4t0r Please see my updated question. Thanks

Comment: @TygerTy I do. When I first started developing with the Ebay API I incorrectly set the scope and I got an auth error due to that and I haven't gotten that since I updated the scope which includes the shipping fulfillment.

Comment: @anothermh httparty worked. I passed all the same headers and body parameters as I did with net/http. Just seems strange.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Net::HTTP is finicky. Always better to use the higher level tools to ensure your options are properly passed to Net::HTTP or other underlying library.

Comment: You have `content-type` in the request twice, probably once as symbol and once as string. Headers should be supplied as string, not as symbols. Could you try update your `@header` to `{ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => "Bearer #{@token}" }` (Notice the change of `:` into `=>`). Could you check the resulting headers with `request.to_hash`? Is `content-type` still present twice after making the change?

Comment: @3limin4t0r That worked! You're amazing! I thought there was no difference between the `:` syntax and the `=>`. I thought it was an update of the same syntax back in like Ruby 2.3.

Comment: @CannonMoyer I've added it as an answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the request content:

> ```
> POST /sell/fulfillment/v1/order/24-04954-08727/shipping_fulfillment
> content-type: application/json
> authorization: Bearer v#i^1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
> accept-encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
> accept: */*
> user-agent: Ruby
> connection: close
> host: api.ebay.com
> content-length: 159
> content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> {"lineItems":[{"lineItemId":"10025031700524"}],"shippedDate":"2020-05- 01T08:05:00.000Z","shippingCarrierCode":"USPS","trackingNumber":"9400111899562795104724"}
> ```

It occurred to me that `content-type` is present twice.

After running some samples in irb it seems that the `net/http` library works with strings, not with symbols. By having a `:` in your `@header` definition the keys are interpreted as symbols.

To quote the [Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Hashes):

> ### Hashes
>
> A hash is created using key-value pairs between `{` and `}`:
>
> ```
> { "a" => 1, "b" => 2 }
> ```
>
> Both the key and value may be any object.
>
> You can create a hash using symbol keys with the following syntax:
>
> ```
> { a: 1, b: 2 }
> ```
>
> This same syntax is used for keyword arguments for a method.
>
> Like [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Symbol.html) literals, you can quote symbol keys.
>
> ```
> { "a 1": 1, "b #{1 + 1}": 2 }
> ```
>
> is equal to
>
> ```
> { :"a 1" => 1, :"b 2" => 2 }
> ```
>
> See [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html) for the methods you may use with a hash.

To use string keys use `=>` instead of `:`.

For you that means changing:

> ```rb
> @header = {
>   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
>   'Authorization': "Bearer #{@token}"
> }
> ```

Into:

```rb
@header = {
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
  'Authorization' => "Bearer #{@token}"
}
```